# PhantomJS does not navigate to the next page after clicking a link

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am having a strange issue with `PhantomJS` or may be I am newbie. I am trying to login on NewEgg.com via Selenium by using PhantomJS. I am using Python for it. Issue is, when I use Firefox as a driver it works well but as soon as I set `PhantomJS` as a driver it does not go to next page hence give message:

```
Exception Message: u'{"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with id \'UserName\'","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"89","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:55372","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/2.7"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\\"using\\": \\"id\\", \\"sessionId\\": \\"aaff4c40-6aaa-11e4-9cb1-7b8841e74090\\", \\"value\\": \\"UserName\\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/aaff4c40-6aaa-11e4-9cb1-7b8841e74090/element"}}' ; Screenshot: available via screen
```

The reason I found after taking screenshot that phantom could not navigate the page and script got finished. How do I sort this out? Code Snippet I tried given below:

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
import datetime

```
my_username = "user@mail.com"
my_password = "password"

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('/Setups/phantomjs-1.9.7-macosx/bin/phantomjs')
firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
#firefox_profile.set_preference('permissions.default.stylesheet', 2)
firefox_profile.set_preference('permissions.default.image', 2)
firefox_profile.set_preference('dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.libflashplayer.so', 'false')
#driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile)
driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)
driver.get('http://newegg.com')
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Log in or Register').click()
driver.save_screenshot('screen.png')
```

I even put `sleep` but it is not making any difference.

Comment: How does the page look like when you take the screenshot?

Comment: It seemed it did not navigate to next page after clicking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Webdriver phantomjs no longer following link on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26560833/webdriver-phantomjs-no-longer-following-link-on-click)

Comment: @ArtjomB. hmm like other I am also not clear how to use your class with script

Comment: @ArtjomB. It would be so helpful if you can add a working example of it.

Comment: Everything that you need is provided in the answer. If you use some other selenium language bindings than the one that I described, you will need to adapt or just update PhantomJS to 1.9.8.

Comment: @ArtjomB Phantom 1.9.8 solves the issue? that I just set driver and it will take care of itself?

Comment: Ok I just tried and it did pass the step but getting stuck on other. I guess that's due to other issue. In such case I will open Question. Please add `1.9.8` as an answer

Comment: Since an answer is provided in the linked question, this question should not receive an answer, but rather marked as a duplicate. I don't want to repeat myself.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this with PhantomJS when the content type of the second page is not correct. A normal browser would just interpret the content dynamically, but Phantom just dies, silently.